# How to play an MP3 file with louder sound?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, itunes

I tried playing an MP3 file with VLC player and iTunes both with largest volume of the player and the Mac OS X system.  The former seems to play a little louder (any way to quantitatively measure?)  I am wondering if there is anything that only involve software settings I can do to make it sound louder.

Comment: Sure there is a quantitave way of measuring that. Get a microphone and record it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VLC select `Tools->Effects and Filters->Audio Effects->Graphic Equalizer->Enable` then increase the preamp and/or band sliders. Also try using the 2-pass option (it seems to work better for multi-channel DVDs than for two-channel video files/MP3s).

[image: VLC Graphic Equalizer]

Comment: I just tested that on an mp3, increased everything there to max, no difference I could hear.

Comment: I can't find the option in VLC on Mac OS X.   I can only find http://i40.tinypic.com/o7r1pd.png  Is that it?  What should I set there?

Comment: Yes, that should do it (is there a preamp slider as well?) There should also be a *Tools* menu item to display the [*Effects and Filters* dialog](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch03.html#id587938). You should also be able to display it with a hotkey (it’s `Ctrl+E` on Windows). (The *Tools* menu item did not exist in older versions, so make sure you are running the latest version—a good idea in general.) Also, you should be able to right-click on VLC and select *Interface -> Effects and Filters*.

Comment: Shift-Cmd-E brings up the window in your screenshot.  So I just need to check "Enable" checkbox, and do nothing else?

Comment: Well you will need to adjust the preamp slider as desired. You can try the 2-pass option and the other sliders if need be (though usually the preamp alone is more than enough to make it too loud).